# Webserver Nginx + PHP FPM Access Denied error with .cgi scripts

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, cgi, permissions

Webserver with Nginx 1.1.19 and PHP 5 FPM work great with serving PHP and showing output of mysql data.

I want to embed nagios in my application and so I needed .cgi scripts for the first time on this server. This didn't work. Then I made a simple echo hello world .cgi script and I still get 'Access Denied'.

I gave the file and all the folders above it Executive permissions (chmod +x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx does not currently support classic cgi.
It does support fastcgi, though.

[Most](http://wiki.nginx.org/SimpleCGI) [solutions](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration#CGI) involve using a wrapper script of some kind to make a cgi script into a fcgi script.

Comment: Thanks, it was not really mentioned in the guides of converting Nagios from Apache2 to Nginx.

I just followed this guide: http://www.howtoforge.com/serving-cgi-scripts-with-nginx-on-debian-squeeze-ubuntu-11.04-p3

And it works flawless!